# Hatch - Error after instalation of the program

Tags: python, hatch

Well i dont know if this is the right place to ask, but I don't know where else to go. so I was trying out Hatch and thought I just finished all of the installation, but then I get this error message:

```
[92m[~] [37mEnter a directory to a password list: crackstation-human-only.txt.gz
C:\Users\-my_username-\Downloads\Privat\Hatch-python3-optimised\main.py:86: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=optionss)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60582/devtools/browser/2b7934f2-07ff-40b0-9d86-be8c732809ce
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-my_username-\Downloads\Privat\Hatch-python3-optimised\main.py", line 128, in <module>
    wizard()
  File "C:\Users\-my_username-\Downloads\Privat\Hatch-python3-optimised\main.py", line 79, in wizard
    brutes(username, username_selector ,password_selector,login_btn_selector,pass_list, website)
  File "C:\Users\-my_username-\Downloads\Privat\Hatch-python3-optimised\main.py", line 90, in brutes
    for line in f:
  File "C:\Users\-my_username-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 4: character maps to <undefined>
```

Im using Hatch from FlorianBord2 github - https://github.com/FlorianBord2/Hatch-python3-optimised/blob/master/main.py, and a lenovo computer with windows 10
what do I do?

hopefully someone can help:)

Comment: Ask FlorianBord2 by submitting an issue.

Comment: he has dissabeled issues, so cant

Comment: Submit a bug report the way he wants to, then

Comment: Looks like software that's been tested on Linux but you're trying to run it on Windows. They probably forgot to declare the encoding when opening the input file, and Windows seems to default to cp1252 in your case, while the data is probably utf-8.

Comment: For a quick fix, trying changing line 82 to `f = open(pass_list, 'r', encoding="utf-8")` and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: But if the program has never been tested on Windows, you might run into lots more similar issues. (I speak from experience: for a while I was the only developer running one of our projects on Windows, and I have had to apply this exact patch quite a few times. The issue comes from the fact that on Linux and Mac, Python 3's `open()` defaults to utf-8, but not on Windows.)